# QEMU hardware error 0x80000021

Tags: hardware, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu

I'm trying to run [Hiren's BootCD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/download/) on QEMU but it throws a hardware error 0x80000021 on a Core 2 Duo, maybe there is some parameter missing to fix that.

```
$ kvm --version
QEMU emulator version 1.0 (qemu-kvm-1.0), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
$ uname -a
Linux tiago-pc 3.2.0-37-generic #58-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 24 15:28:10 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ lsb_release -r
Release:    12.04
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
output file: http://pastebin.com/7afK8dZ6
$ kvm -m 512 -cdrom PATH_TO_THE_FILE/HBCD_15.2.iso -boot once=d
KVM: entry failed, hardware error 0x80000021
```

[full output file](http://pastebin.com/Qu2exEfN)

The boot list is shown, but doesn't matter which option I choose it always gives the same error, I've tried on **qemu-system-i386** and **qemu-system-x86_64** as well, resulting in the same problem.

I do **upgrade** and **dist-upgrade** every day, and I've just tried to run it on 12.10 livecd (of course, without upgrade), unless it was fixed after the release the problem still happens!

Some sites I found with this error says to add the parameter **-cpu core2duo** or **-enable-kvm** but it didn't solve the bug.

```
Screen: http://img15.imageshack.us/img15/2797/ss00.png
```

Comment: I fixed the problem, can I share the solution? Please, reopen the question!

Comment: I've tried to install 12.10 on a external drive and update till the kernel last version, but the problem persisted, I even installed the drivers from ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers didn't work.

So I used the external drive in an older computer, with Pentium 4, and it worked, so I came back to my computer and tried to disable some flags on bios, and I discovered when I disable the Vanderpool it works, but QEMU doesn't use the CPU virtualization, unfortunately I have to live without it, but at least works.

Comment: @TiagoPimenta - question has been reopened - please create an answer and you can also mark it as accepted as well to close the question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem disabling on BIOS the flag Vanderpool, it seems Core 2 Duo don't have a full virtualization support, since the error says "the guest maybe running in big real mode which is not supported on less recent Intel processors", QEMU runs well on a Core i5 I have at home, and on a Pentium 4 without VT support!

Well, I hope QEMU could workaround these kind of problem in the future, but for now the problem is fixed.

Comment: You can also use **-no-kvm** option on qemu-system-i386

Answer (score 1):

It is a known (kernel) bug:

http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.emulators.kvm.devel/91786

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1045027

There is a fix released for Ubuntu 12.10 but that I know (from my google search) not 12.04.

There are also reports of this error being thrown when you allocate insufficient memory to your guest. Try allocating 1024 Mb.

https://serverfault.com/questions/446015/windows-server-2008-instance-on-kvm-stuck-in-pause-mode

Comment: If it's a kernel bug fixed in 12.10, then installing the kernel from 12.10 via the `linux-generic-lts-quantal` package will do the trick.